# Altair log position of tooltip on click to file

Tags: python, maps, altair, vega-lite

I aim to keep a log (log file or dataframe) of all the countries a user has clicked on. I am trying to log the `id` of the tooltip on click, but do not know how I can extract any values. I'd be happy about any advice on how to extract values. Getting the country name and highlighting the country work well so far.

Any help is appreciated, also if altair does not support this solution, a pointer to if/how other frameworks accomplish this would also be helpful.

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st
from vega_datasets import data


@st.cache
def get_iso_names(url: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(url)


# Data generators for the background
sphere = alt.sphere()
graticule = alt.graticule()

# Source of land data
source = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, "countries")
iso_name_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefangabos/world_countries/master/data/countries/en/world.csv"
country_names = get_iso_names(iso_name_url)

click = alt.selection_multi(empty="none")

# Layering and configuring the components
background = (
    alt.layer(
        alt.Chart(sphere).mark_geoshape(fill="lightblue"),
        alt.Chart(graticule).mark_geoshape(stroke="white", strokeWidth=0.5),
        alt.Chart(source)
        .mark_geoshape(
            stroke="black",
            strokeWidth=0.15,
        )
        .encode(
            tooltip=[
                alt.Tooltip("name:N", title="Country"),
            ],
            # color=alt.condition(hover, alt.value("firebrick"), "none"),
            color=alt.condition(click, alt.value("firebrick"), alt.value("white")),
        )
        .transform_lookup(
            lookup="id",
            from_=alt.LookupData(country_names, "id", ["name"]),
        ),
    )
    .add_selection(click)
    .project("naturalEarth1")
    .properties(width=1200, height=800)
)


st.altair_chart(
    background.interactive(),
    # (background + foreground).interactive(),
    use_container_width=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly with Altair, you would need to use a dashboard library that supports the functionality of extracting data from the selected points, such as Panel (might be added to streamlit in the future). More info here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1153